# Paypal Recurring Payment using REST API from Phonegap App

Tags: paypal, phonegap

I want to add auto subscription payment for service in one of my PhoneGap Application. I tried with Paypal plugin but it doesnt support the auto recurring payment. Any suggestion how to achive this ?
I am also flexible if its achievable using REST API and CURL from PHP API.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just review the [Subscriptions documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/) and you should see all the info you need about doing it with REST API.